# Use $AND in MongoDB (querys)

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I am starting to use the NoSQL database MongoDB and doing some courses of MongoDB.

I am trying to resolve two querys but I can't :(

Are the followings:

*What is the name of the listing in the sample_airbnb.listingsAndReviews dataset that accommodates more than 6 people and has exactly 50 reviews?*

```
db.listingsAndReviews.find({"$and": [{"accommodates" {"$gt": 6}}, {"reviews": {"$size": 50}}]}).count()
```

*How many companies in the sample_training.companies dataset were either founded in 2004 and either have the social category_code or web category_code, or were founded in the month of October and also either have the social category_code or web category_code?*

```
db.companies.find({"$and": [{"$or": ["foundation_year": 2004], ["founded_month": 10]}],[{"$or": ["category_code": "web"], ["category_code": "social"]}]}).count()
```

But any of these two querys works, what can I be doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB provides an implicit AND operation when specifying a comma separated list of expressions. You only need to use `$AND` if you are evaluating the same field.

For the first question you must use the `number_of_reviews`, like so:

```
{ number_of_reviews: 50, accommodates: { $gt: 6 } }
```

For the second question you must use the correct sintax for $OR, like so:

```
{ $and: [ { $or: [ { founded_year: 2004 }, { founded_month: 10 } ] }, { $or: [ { category_code: 'social'}, { category_code: 'web' }  ] } ] }
```

Comment: Hi Haniel, thanks for your help! Both queryes give me 0 as a output and at least there is 1 :/

Comment: Hi, which operation?

Comment: No, the first works :), the second operation give me 0

Comment: Could you verify the database? should be the `sample_training`

Comment: It's working, was my bad! wow thanks a lot Haniel! I was trying to use it in the mongo shell and there I couldn't do it work but in the Atlas of MongoDB works fine! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

This was the query that I used :

```js
db.companies.find({ "$or" : [ {"founded_year" : 2004 , "$or" : [ {"category_code" : "social"} , {category_code : "web"} ] } , {"founded_month" : 10 , "$or" : [ {"category_code" : "social"} , {category_code : "web"} ] } ] }).count()
```

Answer was correct.

Comment: you have to use code snippet from editor tool instead posting it as is. it looks ugly..! How to write good answer? - stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer @M D A

Answer (score 0):

```
db.companies.find({"$and":[{"$or":[{"founded_year": 2004},{"founded_month": 10}]},{"$or":[{"category_code": "social"}, {"category_code": "web"}]}]}).count()
```

Comment: I have formatted your code as a code block, but please read [answer]. Code is much more helpful when accompanied by an explanation.